# How do I get (gci).count to return proper numeric values for empty or single-item lists?

Tags: powershell

> Related:
>   [How can I write a script to count files modified within a particular month?](https://superuser.com/questions/591160/how-can-i-write-a-script-to-count-files-modified-within-a-particular-month)

When I try to get a count of items, e.g. with `(gci).count` to count files in a folder, PowerShell returns no output for empty lists or lists containing only one item. It works fine for lists containing multiple items, though.

[image]

How can I get PowerShell to return proper numeric values for all cases? i.e.: How can I get it to output an actual zero for empty lists, and output one for single-item lists?

My particular use case, as further described in the related question linked above, is to get a count of items in a list that results from piping a `gci` command's output to `where`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that powershell, when returning an array of 1 item will simply collapse the array into that single item.

Before version 3, this would result is an object without the expected `count` property and your result would be empty. This has been "fixed" in [version 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx).

So you have 2 options:

1. Upgrade to Powershell v3
2. Apply the following workaround where you always wrap your results as an array type `@()`:

   @(gci).count

Comment: You particularly call out arrays of 1 item in your answer - does the fix work for empty arrays as well? Also, wouldn't that workaround be `@((gci).count)`?

Comment: Hrm. Interesting. Your initial description of the workaround doesn't quite match up with the actual usage. And the usage itself is a bit confusing in that it doesn't actually need any extra parenthesis. Good news is, it works for empty arrays also.

Comment: @Iszi The workaround works in the general case since the @() denotes an array object which always has a count property.  The contents of the array is populated with the results of `gci`. An array can be empty, so if `gci` return nothing, you get an empty array. You also don;t need any more brackets than I show, powershell will know that gci is a complete expression in this context.